# Which type of cats learn fast? Persian or any other?

Tags: cats, behavior

Which type of cats learn fast? Persian or any other?

Please suggest me any one so that I can buy one?

Comment: Regardless of cat breed it is important to adopt a young kitten. Building bond with adult or even adolescent cats is much more difficult.

Comment: This question is not opinion based and plently of solid study and evidence is there. It is rather disappointing that many in this site prefer cat breeds as not a subject to be given importance upon.  https://iheartcats.com/cat-breeds-with-dog-like-qualities/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you want to teach a cat, but you should be aware that cats are harder to train than dogs or even horses. You cannot say "sit down" and expect the cat to actually sit down. That will never work. 
And as with humans and any animals, there are always differences in personality. Even in breeds that are supposed to be clever there will always be animals with higher and lower intelligence.

More importantly, there are animals more ore less ready to **cooperate, and that is what you actually want**. What's the use when your cat understands what you want to teach her but doesn't care about actually doing it?

So first, you need to think about what **exactly** you expect from your cat and then research about different cat breeds and their temperament. I won't do that for you because I don't know what your requirements are.

If you work in a circus and want to teach your cat tricks for the shows, select a high-energy breed. A female is more likely to cooperate than a male.

If you want a cat as a pet for your home and "just" want to teach her not to walk over your coffe table, the breed doesn't matter. *Every* cat is able to understand that. If your cat still does forbidden things, you didn't teach her in the correct way or she just doesn't care about your rules. That's the thing with cats, they have a mind of their own. If that bothers you too much, you might think about having a different animal as a pet.